# MQTT reconecction loop during exception, how to structure the script

Tags: python, mqtt, esp32, micropython, thonny

I'm trying to write a temperature controller for a ESP32 which sends the sensor reading via mqtt to mosquitto installed on a rasperry pi. The code runs, as long as wifi is connected and mosquitto is running on the raspberry pi. As soon as the ESP32 is not connected to wifi or the mqtt broker cannot be reached the code ends in a reconnect loop.
The idea is that the temperature controller side of the code keeps running even when there is an error with wifi or the mqtt.

[Standard behaviour with good wifi / mqtt connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j50M2.png)
[Error with mosquitto stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOQh5.png)

As im fairly new to programming i suspect my code is quite messy and therefore i get this error. I tried different way on arringing my functions and loops but had no luck.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction on how to structure my code so that it can handle the exeptions

```
from machine import Pin, SoftI2C
import ssd1306
import machine
import utime
import onewire, ds18x20, time
from umqtt.robust import MQTTClient
import ubinascii
from machine import RTC
import os
import micropython
import network
import esp
esp.osdebug(None)
import asyncio
import gc
gc.collect()


###################### define global variables##########################
tempsetpoint = 30.0   # temperature set point
last_message = 0
message_interval = 5
integral = 0
lastupdate = utime.time()  
lasterror = 0
output1=0
output2=0
checkin = 0

maxtemperaturedifference = 10

datalogging = False


Kp=100.   # 400 Proportional term - Basic steering (This is the first parameter you should tune for a particular setup)
Ki=.01   # .05 Integral term - Compensate for heat loss by vessel
Kd=0.  # Derivative term - to prevent overshoot due to inertia - if it is zooming towards setpoint this
         # will cancel out the proportional term due to the large negative gradient
output1= 0
output2=0

maxtemperaturedifference = 10

################### Connect to WIFI and MQTT server ##################################

ssid = 'Inabnit'
password = 'Buochserhorn'
mqtt_server = '192.168.50.31'
"""
station = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)

station.active(True)
station.connect(ssid, password)

while station.isconnected() == False:
  pass

print('Connection to WIFI successful')
"""
class wifi:
  def __init__(self, ssid, password):
    self.ssid = ssid
    self.password = password

  def connect(self):
    station = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    station.active(True)
    station.connect(self.ssid, self.password)
    while station.isconnected() == False:
      pass

    print("Connection to %s successful" %self.ssid)

credentials = wifi("Inabnit", "Buochserhorn")
credentials.connect()


    ################### MQTT Setup ##################################
client_id = ubinascii.hexlify(machine.unique_id())

topic_pub_temp1 = b'esp/ds18b20/temperature1' #topic name, add more if needed
topic_pub_temp2 = b'esp/ds18b20/temperature2' #topic name, add more if needed
topic_pub_output1 = b'esp/mosfet/output1' #topic name, add more if needed
topic_pub_output2 = b'esp/mosfet/output2' #topic name, add more if needed



    ################### RTC setup ##################################

rtc=RTC()
timeStamp=0

    ################### Mosfet setup ##################################

 #define mosfet1 pin
p0 = machine.Pin(0)
pwm0 = machine.PWM(p0)
pwm0.freq(500)
pwm0.duty_u16(0)

 #define mosfet2 pin
p0 = machine.Pin(1)
pwm1 = machine.PWM(p0)
pwm1.freq(500)
pwm1.duty_u16(0)

    ################### DS18b20 setup ##################################

#define temp sensor pin
ds_pin = machine.Pin(21)
ds_sensor = ds18x20.DS18X20(onewire.OneWire(ds_pin))


 
#roms = ds_sensor.scan()
#print('Found DS devices: ', roms)
Sensor1 = b"('/\x07\x00\x00\x00<"
Sensor2 = b'\x10Fd\x16\x03\x08\x00\x91'
Sensor3 = b'\x10Fd\x16\x03\x08\x00\x80' #update rom with actual address


     ################### OLED Setup ##################################

#setup oled
WIDTH  = 128                                            # oled display width
HEIGHT = 64                                             # oled display height
 
i2c = SoftI2C(scl=Pin(8), sda=Pin(9))
 
oled_width = 128
oled_height = 64
oled = ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(oled_width, oled_height, i2c)

    ################### Functions ##################################



######################## Logging function#########################
with open('savedata.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('Temperature Data Logging')
    f.write('\n')
    
def logData():
    timeTuple=rtc.datetime()
    file_size=os.stat('/savedata.txt')
    if(file_size[6]<2000000):
        try:
            with open('savedata.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(str(timeTuple[4])+':'+str(timeTuple[5])+':'+str(timeTuple[6])+ ',')
                f.write(str(temp)+ ',')
                f.write(str(output1))
                #f.write(scaled_output)
                f.write('\n')
                print("Data Saved!")
        
        except:
                print("Error! Could not save")
 
################scaling function to scale X-XXX to X-XXX exapmple: scale_value(output, 0, 100, 0, 65535)#############
def scale_value(value, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max):
  scaled_value = (value - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min
  return int(scaled_value)

################################
def checktemperature():
    global temp_max
    global temp1
    global temp2
    global tempdifference
    #global temp3 #uncomment if 3 sensors will be used
    ds_sensor.convert_temp()
    temp1 = round(ds_sensor.read_temp(Sensor1),1)
    temp2 = round(ds_sensor.read_temp(Sensor2),1)
    #temp3 = round(ds_sensor.read_temp(Sensor3),1) #uncomment if 3 sensors will be used

    
    temp_max = round(max(temp1, temp2),1)
    #temp_max = round(max(temp1, temp2, temp3),1) #uncomment if 3 sensors will be used
    
    #print(temp_max)
    tempdifference = abs(temp1-temp2)
  
################################ 
def displayonOLED():
     #display data on the oled    
    # Clear the oled display in case it has junk on it.
    oled.fill(0)
    oled.contrast(255)  # bright
    # Add some text
    #oled.text("Temperature ",12,5)
    oled.text("Setpoint: ",1,5)
    oled.text(str(tempsetpoint),88,5)
    oled.text("Sensor 1: ",1,15)
    oled.text(str(temp1),88,15)
    oled.text("Sensor 2: ",1,25)
    oled.text(str(temp2),88,25)
    oled.text("Sensor Max: ",1,35)
    oled.text(str(temp_max),88,35)
    oled.text("Output 1: ",1,45)
    oled.text(str(output1),88,45)
    # Finally update the oled display so the image & text is displayed
    oled.show()
###################################    
def displayonOLED_tempdiff():
     #display data on the oled    
    # Clear the oled display in case it has junk on it.
    oled.fill(0)
    """### Blink OLED###
    oled.show()
    utime.sleep_ms(200)
    oled.fill(1)
    oled.show()
    utime.sleep_ms(200)
    """
    oled.fill(0)

    oled.contrast(255)  # bright
    # Add some text

    oled.text("Temp diff.> 10",1,5)
    oled.text("Sensor 1: ",1,15)
    oled.text(str(temp1),88,15)
    oled.text("Sensor 2: ",1,25)
    oled.text(str(temp2),88,25)

    # Finally update the oled display so the image & text is displayed
    oled.show()
    
    
####################### Connect to MQTT Broker###################
def connect_mqtt():
  global client_id, mqtt_server
  try:
    client = MQTTClient(client_id, mqtt_server)
    #client = MQTTClient(client_id, mqtt_server, user=your_username, password=your_password)
    client.DEBUG = True

    client.connect()
    #client.loop_start()
    print('Connected to %s MQTT broker' % (mqtt_server))

    return client
  except:
    print("Error: MQTT client not reachable")
     

######################### restart MQTT
def restart_and_reconnect():
  failsafe()
  print('Failed to connect to MQTT broker. Reconnecting...')
  #time.sleep(10)
  #machine.reset()

###########publish to mqtt#################
def publishtomqtt():
    global client_id, mqtt_server
    temp1_mqtt = (b'{0:3.1f}'.format(temp1))
    temp2_mqtt = (b'{0:3.1f}'.format(temp2))
    output1_mqtt = (b'{0:3.1f}'.format(output1))
    output2_mqtt = (b'{0:3.1f}'.format(output2))

    try:
        client = MQTTClient(client_id, mqtt_server)
        #client = MQTTClient(client_id, mqtt_server, user=your_username, password=your_password)
        client.DEBUG = True

        client.connect()
        #client.loop_start()
        print('Connected to %s MQTT broker' % (mqtt_server))
    
    
    except OSError as e:
      #restart_and_reconnect()
      print("Error puplishtomqtt")
      
      
    
    #client = connect_mqtt()
    client.publish(topic_pub_temp1, temp1_mqtt)
    client.publish(topic_pub_temp2, temp2_mqtt)
    client.publish(topic_pub_output1, output1_mqtt)
    client.publish(topic_pub_output2, output2_mqtt)
    
    client.disconnect()
    

#######################Heater Failsafe##############################

def failsafe():
    pwm0.duty_u16(0)
    pwm1.duty_u16(0)
    print("Heating Stopped!")
  
    
    
    ################### Main Logic ##################################


checktemperature()
 
while True:
    if (time.ticks_ms()-timeStamp)>5000:
        timeStamp=time.ticks_ms()

    if tempdifference <= maxtemperaturedifference:

        try:           
            checktemperature()
            displayonOLED()
                        
            if (time.ticks_ms()-timeStamp)>5000:
                if datalogging == True :
                    logData()
                try:    
                    publishtomqtt()
                except Exception as e:
                    print( "An error has occurred!")
                    
                timeStamp=time.ticks_ms()
                
                

            
            now = utime.time()
            dt= now-lastupdate
            
            if dt > checkin:
                error=tempsetpoint-temp1
                integral = integral + dt * error
                derivative = (error - lasterror)/dt
                output1 = Kp * error + Ki * integral + Kd * derivative
                #print(str(output)+"= Kp term: "+str(Kp*error)+" + Ki term:" + str(Ki*integral) + "+ Kd term: " + str(Kd*derivative))
                output1 = max(min(100, output1), 0) # Clamp output between 0 and 100
                scaled_output1 = scale_value(output1, 0, 100, 0, 65535)
                
                error=tempsetpoint-temp2
                integral = integral + dt * error
                derivative = (error - lasterror)/dt
                output2 = Kp * error + Ki * integral + Kd * derivative
                #print(str(output)+"= Kp term: "+str(Kp*error)+" + Ki term:" + str(Ki*integral) + "+ Kd term: " + str(Kd*derivative))
                output2 = max(min(100, output2), 0) # Clamp output between 0 and 100
                scaled_output2 = scale_value(output2, 0, 100, 0, 65535)
                
                print('Output1: ', round(output1),'%    ', 'Output2: ', round(output2),'%    ', 'Temp_max:  ', temp_max,'°C     ', 'Temp1: ', temp1, '°C    ', 'Temp2: ', temp2, '°C')
                #print('Output: ', output,'%    ', 'Temp_max:  ', temp_max,'°C     ', 'Temp1: ', temp1, '°C    ', 'Temp2: ', temp2, '°C', 'Temp3: ', temp3, '°C') #uncomment if 3 sensors will be used
                
                if output1>0:  
                    pwm0.duty_u16(scaled_output1)
                if output2>0:  
                    pwm1.duty_u16(scaled_output2)

                else:
                    pwm0.duty_u16(0)
                    pwm1.duty_u16(0)

                #utime.sleep(.1)
                lastupdate = now
                lasterror = error
                
        except Exception as e:
            if (time.ticks_ms()-timeStamp)>1000:
                timeStamp=time.ticks_ms()
                failsafe()
                print('error encountered:'+str(e))
                
                utime.sleep(checkin)
    else:
            if (time.ticks_ms()-timeStamp)>1000:
                timeStamp=time.ticks_ms()
                print("Temperature difference >5!")
                checktemperature()
                displayonOLED_tempdiff()
                failsafe()
```

Comment: Hi @Inabnit, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include the *text* of the error in the question, not a picture of the error. Screen readers can't read the text from the picture and it can't be searched.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to structure your code and provided some examples on handling exceptions in the code.

```
from machine import Pin, SoftI2C
import ssd1306
import machine
import utime
import onewire
import ds18x20
from umqtt.robust import MQTTClient
import ubinascii
from machine import RTC
import os
import network
import esp

# ... (Other imports)

###################### Define Global Variables ##########################
tempsetpoint = 30.0
integral = 0
lastupdate = utime.time()
lasterror = 0
output1 = 0
output2 = 0
checkin = 0
maxtemperaturedifference = 10
datalogging = False
Kp = 100.0
Ki = 0.01
Kd = 0.0

# ... (Other global variables)

ssid = 'Inabnit'
password = 'Buochserhorn'
mqtt_server = '192.168.50.31'

# ... (Other configurations)

class Wifi:
    def __init__(self, ssid, password):
        self.ssid = ssid
        self.password = password

    def connect(self):
        station = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
        station.active(True)
        station.connect(self.ssid, self.password)
        while not station.isconnected():
            pass
        print("Connection to %s successful" % self.ssid)

credentials = Wifi("Inabnit", "Buochserhorn")
credentials.connect()

# ... (Other configurations)

client_id = ubinascii.hexlify(machine.unique_id())
topic_pub_temp1 = b'esp/ds18b20/temperature1'
topic_pub_temp2 = b'esp/ds18b20/temperature2'
topic_pub_output1 = b'esp/mosfet/output1'
topic_pub_output2 = b'esp/mosfet/output2'

# ... (Other configurations)


###################### Functions ##########################

def connect_mqtt():
    global client_id, mqtt_server
    try:
        client = MQTTClient(client_id, mqtt_server)
        client.DEBUG = True
        client.connect()
        print('Connected to %s MQTT broker' % mqtt_server)
        return client
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: MQTT client not reachable")
        return None

def restart_and_reconnect():
    failsafe()
    print('Failed to connect to MQTT broker. Reconnecting...')

def publish_to_mqtt(client):
    if client is not None:
        temp1_mqtt = b'{0:3.1f}'.format(temp1)
        temp2_mqtt = b'{0:3.1f}'.format(temp2)
        output1_mqtt = b'{0:3.1f}'.format(output1)
        output2_mqtt = b'{0:3.1f}'.format(output2)

        try:
            client.publish(topic_pub_temp1, temp1_mqtt)
            client.publish(topic_pub_temp2, temp2_mqtt)
            client.publish(topic_pub_output1, output1_mqtt)
            client.publish(topic_pub_output2, output2_mqtt)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error publishing to MQTT:", e)
        finally:
            client.disconnect()

# ... (Other functions)

###################### Main Logic ##########################

checktemperature()

while True:
    if (utime.ticks_ms() - timeStamp) > 5000:
        timeStamp = utime.ticks_ms()

    if tempdifference <= maxtemperaturedifference:
        try:
            checktemperature()
            displayonOLED()

            if (utime.ticks_ms() - timeStamp) > 5000:
                if datalogging:
                    logData()
                try:
                    mqtt_client = connect_mqtt()
                    if mqtt_client:
                        publishtomqtt(mqtt_client)
                except Exception as e:
                    print("An error has occurred:", e)

                timeStamp = utime.ticks_ms()

            now = utime.time()
            dt = now - lastupdate

            if dt > checkin:
                error = tempsetpoint - temp1
                integral = integral + dt * error
                derivative = (error - lasterror) / dt
                output1 = Kp * error + Ki * integral + Kd * derivative
                output1 = max(min(100, output1), 0)
                scaled_output1 = scale_value(output1, 0, 100, 0, 65535)

                error = tempsetpoint - temp2
                integral = integral + dt * error
                derivative = (error - lasterror) / dt
                output2 = Kp * error + Ki * integral + Kd * derivative
                output2 = max(min(100, output2), 0)
                scaled_output2 = scale_value(output2, 0, 100, 0, 65535)

                print('Output1: ', round(output1), '%    ', 'Output2: ', round(output2), '%    ',
                      'Temp_max:  ', temp_max, '°C     ', 'Temp1: ', temp1, '°C    ', 'Temp2: ', temp2, '°C')
                if output1 > 0:
                    pwm0.duty_u16(scaled_output1)
                if output2 > 0:
                    pwm1.duty_u16(scaled_output2)
                else:
                    pwm0.duty_u16(0)
                    pwm1.duty_u16(0)

                lastupdate = now
                lasterror = error

        except Exception as e:
            if (utime.ticks_ms() - timeStamp) > 1000:
                timeStamp = utime.ticks_ms()
                failsafe()
                print('Error encountered:', e)
                utime.sleep(checkin)
    else:
        if (utime.ticks_ms() - timeStamp) > 1000:
            timeStamp = utime.ticks_ms()
            print("Temperature difference > 5!")
            checktemperature()
            displayonOLED_tempdiff()
            failsafe()
```

In the modified code, I have added some exception handling to improve robustness in handling potential errors. Here's a summary of the exceptions handled in various parts of the code:

MQTT Connection Exception:

In the connect_mqtt function, an exception is caught if there is an issue connecting to the MQTT broker.

```
try:
    # MQTT connection logic
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: MQTT client not reachable")
```

MQTT Publishing Exception:

In the publish_to_mqtt function, exceptions are caught if there are errors during the process of publishing messages to MQTT topics.

```
try:
    # MQTT publishing logic
except Exception as e:
    print("Error publishing to MQTT:", e)
finally:
    # Disconnect the MQTT client even if an exception occurred
    client.disconnect()
```

Main Logic Exception:

In the main logic loop, a general exception handler is added to catch any unexpected errors that might occur during the execution of the main loop.

```
try:
    # Main logic
except Exception as e:
    if (utime.ticks_ms() - timeStamp) > 1000:
        timeStamp = utime.ticks_ms()
        failsafe()
        print('Error encountered:', e)
        utime.sleep(checkin)
```

These exceptions are designed to catch errors such as network connectivity issues when connecting to the MQTT broker or unexpected errors in the main logic of the program. The specific exception types (Exception) are used for simplicity, and in a production environment, you might want to handle more specific exceptions based on the nature of potential errors.

Comment: Thank you for this generous proposal and the explenations! I will have a look at the code, try it and report back.